# want to place my button image to specific place in DispForm ribbon by using sequence number?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

Currently Im working on sharepoint designer 2010 DidpForm.aspx page. By using this I have placed one delete button(red colored image shown below) logo on ribbon. I given sequence no 11 so it is showing beside edit item. But i want to place this logo under 'delete item' button. For this howmuch sequence number i have to take here?!

See the following image here for better understanding..

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

You need to set two properties  `Sequence` and `TemplateAlias`. You cannot put the icon under the Delete item as it seems that the maximum icons you can put in this column is three. If you give `Sequence="44"` and `TemplateAlias="o2"`. This is what you will get:
[image]

However, if you set `Sequence="55"` and `TemplateAlias="o2"`. This is the result:
[image]

Full XML may look something like this:

```
<CommandUIDefinition
 Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.Controls._children">
    <Button
     Id="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.Controls.ExportVersionHistory"
     Alt="Export version history of the item to Microsoft Excel."
     LabelText="Export"
     Image16by16="/_layouts/15/images/NY.ExportVersionHistory/Excel_Small.png"
     Image32by32="/_layouts/15/images/NY.ExportVersionHistory/Excel_32.gif"
     Command="ExportVersionHistory"
     Sequence="55"
     TemplateAlias="o2"
     ToolTipTitle="Export Version History"
     ToolTipDescription="Export version history of the item to Microsoft Excel."/>
</CommandUIDefinition>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Actually I'm using OOTB . By using sp designer, I placed button and it showing only one option ie, "Sequence number" . Then where can I get XML file to change TemplateAlias?

Comment: Try adding TemplateAlias property and save and see if it has any effect.

Comment: Can you share what you have already written in the XML and what happens if you add TemplateAlias property, save it and browse the page.

Comment: First I don't understand why you are manipulating that file. Second I can see TemplateAlias property over there in the buttons. What is the issue then?

Comment: From the above.. you can find your button ExportversionHistory on xml file. But my case i didnt find the button ie, what I created through sp designer.